# Windows batch compare files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have this code, that will compare 4 text files N1.txt N2.txt etc. with out.txt.

```
set A=4
for /L %%r in (1,1,%A%) do (
   findstr /vxg:N%%r.txt out.txt>>MissingValues.txt
   for /f %%a in ('^<MissingValues.txt find /v /c ""') do echo %%a differences
)
```

If i run the part inside the for loop alone, it works fine.
When i add the for loop, i am just getting the same values inside the text file, and not only the missing values. What is wrong with the code ?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you need to get at the end. If you need the number of differences for each of the Nx files, replace `>>` with `>` to reset the missing values file for each iteration. If this is not the case, please, indicate what the expected output of the code should be.

Comment: @MCND the expected output is only the missing values, so as an example 

text1:

111

222

333

text2:

111

222

The output will be 333

Answer (score 0):

I found a code that works for my files, it's a bit slow but works fine for my files.

```
@echo off

set A=4
for /L %%r in (1,1,%A%) do (
for /f "delims=" %%a in (out.txt) do (
   find "%%a" <"IMSI%%r.txt" || >>result.txt echo %%a
 )
)
```